# How to display a dataset in the listview in windows form app using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am using this code to display the data from a table.
code:

```
foreach (DataTable table in companyDetails.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
                for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr[i].ToString());
                }
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            listView1.View = View.List;
        }
```

Output: [Output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8Tk.png)

Expected output: [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCvIW.png)

Id  Name        Address

1   Shishank    Agra

2   Satyam  Delhi

Comment: You can use `Detailed` view. Why not using a `DataGridView`? Then you can easily set `dataGridView1.DataSource = table;`.

Comment: ...assuming you have added Columns to your ListView -- If you actually have more than one DataTable, use the DataSet's Relations to design a master/detail view using, as mentioned, DataGridView Controls (which are built for this kind of presentation). It also simplify UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE procedures (using a configured DataAdapter).